# How to specify grid width once in Bootstrap 3x (instead of once per media size)?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, grid

Twitter bootstrap 3.x changes the grid model so that you set grid cell width *and* which media size to apply it to:

```
 e.g. col-md-4,  col-lg-12    (previously span4, span5)
```

Is there some short hand to specify the same cell size for any media size? So I don't have to do this to get the item to be a 4 grid cell across all media sizes:

```
 <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">...</div>
```

Comment: there is no such shortcut mentioned in bootstrap docs..

Comment: As mentioned by @Bart below, the size rules will 'bubble up' from smallest to largest. So if you just specify the xs size (e.g. col-xs-12) that will also be used as the sm, md and lg sizes.

Comment: @Jagu +1 for the term bubble up that I tried to find in my answer and couldn't get it :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes! there's absolutely no need to use it as you shown.
You can use `<div class="col-xs-4">` for all grid sizes. Bootstrap Grid use the smaller for all the grid up.

also you can use `<div class="col-md-4">` to apply 4 for md and lg size but block on lower media size.

Bootstrap is smart enough to understand that if at a smaller XS size the column should be of size 4 to apply to the rest of greater width size with no problem. (you can, of course, override specifying each grid size)

hope it's clear enough :D

Comment: Oh of course! I'm embarrassed I didn't think of that. Thank you so much.